# NodeMCU memory leak in http module (post)

Tags: http, memory-leaks, lua, nodemcu

I can reliably reproduce a memory leak in the NodeMCU http module (post), with the following code:

```
msgData="This is some data that is being sent to the server; data is logged by the server"
function logWrite(str)
    str=tostring(tmr.time()).." -> "..tostring(node.heap()).." - "..str
    print(str)
end

function sendData()
    logWrite("sendData(sending)")

    http.post("http://192.168.2.38/DeviceScan.py", "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n", msgData,

      function(rspCode, payload)
          logWrite("sendData(http callback), rspCode="..tostring(rspCode))
          rspCode=nil
          payload=nil
      end)
end

status=tmr.alarm(1, 3000, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, sendData)
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
148 -> 43112 - sendData(sending)
148 -> 42240 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
151 -> 43112 - sendData(sending)
151 -> 42240 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
154 -> 43112 - sendData(sending)
154 -> 42240 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
157 -> 43112 - sendData(sending)
157 -> 42240 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
160 -> 43112 - sendData(sending)
160 -> 42240 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
163 -> 43112 - sendData(sending)
164 -> 42240 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
166 -> 43112 - sendData(sending)
166 -> 42648 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
169 -> 42976 - sendData(sending)
169 -> 42496 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
172 -> 42840 - sendData(sending)
172 -> 42368 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
175 -> 42704 - sendData(sending)
175 -> 42216 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1

636 -> 24536 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
639 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
639 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
642 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
642 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
645 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
645 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
648 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
648 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
651 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
651 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
654 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
654 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
657 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
657 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
660 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
660 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
663 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
663 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
666 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
666 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
669 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
669 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
672 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
672 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
675 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
675 -> 24008 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=200
678 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
678 -> 24536 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
681 -> 24872 - sendData(sending)
681 -> 24400 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
684 -> 24736 - sendData(sending)
684 -> 24264 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
687 -> 24600 - sendData(sending)
687 -> 24128 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
690 -> 24464 - sendData(sending)
690 -> 23992 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
693 -> 24328 - sendData(sending)
693 -> 23856 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1

1240 -> 1688 - sendData(sending)
1240 -> 1216 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
1243 -> 1552 - sendData(sending)
1243 -> 1080 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
1246 -> 1416 - sendData(sending)
1246 -> 944 - sendData(http callback), rspCode=-1
E:M 768

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
```

When the code is first run, the server is up and running and memory usage is stable.

Just prior to timestamp 166 the server is shutdown (emulating a network/server failure) and available memory starts to decrease.

Just prior to timestamp 639 the server is restarted and memory use stablizes.

Just prior to timestamp 678 the server is shutdown again and available memory starts to decrease again. Memory available continues to decrease until a memory allocation error causes a reset.

A clue to the issue is that the memory decrease after each http.post call is directly related to the size of the message body of the http request. The larger the message body the greater the memory available decrease.

I am using the following build:

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: dev
    commit: c0f1e028a64d3aeb399a65b9c44eb512f21da62a
    SSL: true
    modules: file,gpio,http,net,node,rtctime,tmr,uart,wifi
 build  built on: 2016-05-16 19:30
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.1(e67da894)
```

I have not been able to come up with a work around.  Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a single question in your nice description and reproducible test case

> Can this be fixed?

Yes, I'm pretty sure it can be fixed ;-) - in the firmware. There's already an issue for that https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1383.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am glad i am not the only person that has encountered this issue.  For future reference: should these kind of firmware issues be posted here or on github?

Comment: If it's a question then yes. If you're reasonably certain you found a bug and have a good test case like yours then GitHub is the right place. See http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/support/.